# Restrict user for ssh tunnelling

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, restricted-shell

I'm trying to create a user without shell access just for port forwarding through ssh. The shell of the user is set to `/usr/bin/false`, but everytime i try to login through ssh it receive `Permission denied (publickey,password)`. If I add the `/usr/bin/false` to `/etc/shells` it works but I read that this is not recommended. I also created a rule in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of form:

```
Match User tunneluser
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding yes
        AllowAgentForwarding no
        PermitTTY no
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying that SSH fails *authentication* because of the shell, rather than succeed authentication and then fail because of the shell? Considering that the solution is to not use a shell at all, that would still be a problem.

Comment: Here I can't reproduce it. I get authenticated, then it fails because of the shell. What is your OS, distribution and openssh version? Were there specific other settings changed from default?

Comment: I user Arch Linux and the OpenSSH version is OpenSSH_9.3p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023. I did not change anything. From system logs it says "Failed password for user"